# Read dimensions from text file and then add rest of items into array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

Here is how the text file is formatted

```
8   5
String1 String2 String3
```

I want the 8 and 5 to be the respective rows and columns and then add the strings into the array so I have

```
    File f4 = new File(s);
    Scanner in=new Scanner(f4);

    int i = 0;
    int rows = 0;
    int columns = 0;
    while (in.hasNextInt())
    {
        rows = in.nextInt();
        columns = in.nextInt();         
    }

    String[][] data = new String[rows][columns];

    for (int t = 0;i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<data[i].length; j++)
        {
            data[t][j] = in.next();
        }
    }
    return data;
```

However, data is just filled with null strings and the last row of the text file why?

Here is my printing for loop that results in some nulls and some strings

```
for (int t = 0; t < data.length; t++)
        {
            for (int q = 0; q < data[t].length; q++)
            {
                System.out.println(data[t][q]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What kind of strings are in your text file? Are any of them numbers?

Comment: `for (int t = 0;i < data.length; i++) ` I assume this is meant to be: `for (int t = 0;t < data.length; t++)`. Otherwise you only insert into the first row. Similar problem on the next line. it should be `for (int j = 0; j<data[t].length; j++)` I think.

Comment: No just letter characters. However, I discovered something, the array gets populated correctly I believe however when I print the item it just gets set back to null? Edited above.

Comment: Youre totally right! That was the problem everything prints fine now!

Comment: When programming remember to dot your `i`'s and cross your `t`'s! Mostly helped on this question so I could make a bad pun, now I'm going to go evaluate my life decisions.